# Making the border of a Mappolygon clickable - QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtlocation

I have been trying to make the border of a **[MapPolygon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mappolygon.html)** clickable in QML by the following code:

```
MapPolygon{
        id: _poly
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 4
        color: "transparent"
        visible: false
        path: []
        MouseArea{
            id: _polyMousearea
            anchors.fill: _poly.border
            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
            onClicked: {
                var coord = _map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(flightMapMouseArea.mouseX,flightMapMouseArea.mouseY))
console.log(coord )

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

I get the following error:

Unable to assign **QDeclarativeMapLineProperties to QQuickItem** at the line :
**anchors.fill: _poly.border**

Any way to get around this error and make the border clickable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anchors are used to position QtQuick `Item` objects relative to another, the `border` of this element is apparently not an element itself, just a normal grouped property.

Assuming that the `path` contains a QtQuick `Path` one option you have is to make the `MouseArea` fill the whole item, and then use the mouse position in the `onClicked` handler to check with the path's elements on whether they are hit or not.

Comment: Thanks!! I have already implemented this but every click has to be checked if the point lies on any sides of the polygon, i wanted to know if there is an easier/efficient way to get around this